# Error when importing .xlsx into SAS 9.4

Tags: import, sas

I get the following error when I importing a .xlsx file to SAS via File > Import Data.

```
ERROR: Connect: Klassen er ikke registreret
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
NOTE: Import Cancelled.
```

I am using a 64-bit computer. 
I have tried with the following code:

```
proc import out=work.class
  datafile="C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Mappe\hej.xlsx"
  DBMS=EXCELCS;
run;
```

But that do not work. Do anyone know what I should do?

Comment: You say "XLSX" but that is an xls, just as a note: those are different.  What bitness is your Microsoft Office?  Do you have SAS/ACCESS to PC FILES installed?

Comment: I'm going to close this as dup of the other question - it has slightly more informative answers (in particular, a link to Chris H's post).  If it turns out there's a different reason for the issue than the bitness I'll reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Try `DBMS=XLSX` if your file is truly an XLSX file. Your sample points to an XLS file, which you should use `DBMS=EXCEL` to import.

Comment: DBMS=EXCEL should import both types.  DBMS=XLS|XLSX are both fine and different solutions, and I would certainly suggest trying whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to remember my high school German...

A couple of things to check

1. make sure Excel is installed.  PROC IMPORT uses the libraries installed with Excel
2. Make sure Excel and SAS are the same architecture.  I have seen errors like this when one is 32bit and the other is 64bit.
3. Make sure your file is correct in the code.  You say it is an xlsx file, but name it .xls.  There is a big file format difference between these.
4. If is is an XLSX file, then you can use the XLSX libname engine.  `libname blah xlsx 'c:\mydir\myfile.xlsx';`.  I, personally, use this over PROC IMPORT 99% of the time.

Comment: Not sure German will help you with danish...  This is the "Class is not registered" error that's common with these.

Comment: Yeah, I quickly came to the realization it wasn't German!  I was a C student at best!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is a .xlsx file (sorry for the mistake in the text).

I am using a 32bit Microsoft Excel and 64bit SAS. How do I repair this?

I have tried with

    libname blah xlsx 'C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Mappe\hej.xlsx';

But what should I write after that?

Comment: then you use it like any other library.  Your sheets look like data sets.  `data something; set blah.sheet1; ...`